# Pyglet: large-number efficiency: updating vertices vs opengl matrices

Tags: python, opengl, matrix, pyglet, opengl-compat

I want to know what the most computationally efficient way is to animate lots of vertex lists in pyglet.

Most tutorials and discussions I have found online recommend the use of matrices. I have a some scepticism, since these focus on a small number of distinct animations. For instance, manipulating the entire render area uniformly, or using push/pop matrices on ~3 objects. I am trying to create a personal interface for simulation rendering, and the notion of 100+ objects with individual animation specifics is not uncommon at all.

So far, I have been using manual calculation of vertices for updates, then setting each vertexlist's vertices to the updated variant. I worry that matrices will be less efficient. As an illustration of the scenarios I worry about, considering this:

[Image of my Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a3jV.png)

A simple binary tree of tier 10 contains 2047 line segments, amounting to 2047 vertex lists and 8188 vertex coordinates in 2D, 12282 in 3D. I want to animate it, so it curls up on itself and out again. I do this by changing the angle between two branches. Here is my current approach (without inits etc):

```
class Branch(object):
    def update(self, parent_x, parent_y, change_angle_by):
        #calculate new vertices
        self.x0, self.y0 = parent_x, parent_y
        self.angle_change = change_angle_by
        self.angle += change_angle_by
        self.x1 = self.x0 + self.length * cos(self.angle)
        self.y1 = self.y0 + self.length * sin(self.angle)

        #update vertexlist vertices
        self.vertexlist.vertices = [self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1]

        #recurse
        if len(self.branches) > 0:
            self.branches[0].update(self.x1, self.y1, change_angle_by)
            self.branches[1].update(self.x1, self.y1, -change_angle_by)
```

All vertex lists are part of a single batch, which is drawn at the end of all recursive updates. Using unique groups would miss the VertexDomain optimization batches offer as another point of worry.

Note how the update function acts as a translate by using the end points of the previous branch as start points of the next. I also simply increment the angle through addition, rather than matrix multiplication. The effect of the new angle on the vertices is determined through 1 cosine and 1 sine, not 2 cosines and 2 sines as a 2D rotation matrix consists of. All in all, this seems far more efficient computationally than matrix use could be. What am i missing that makes matrix multiplication more efficient than variable copying and addition?

Calculating the vertices through recursive relative coordinates takes a cosine, a sine, two multiplications, and three additions per vertexlist. Constructing the appropriate transformation matrix of each line segment would amount to one translation matrix and one rotation matrix, for every segment, for every frame. Something along these lines:

```py
class Branch(object):
    def update(self, change_angle_by):
        self.relative_angle += change_angle_by
        if len(self.branches) > 0:
            self.branches[0].update(change_angle_by)
            self.branches[1].update(-change_angle_by)

class BranchGroup(pyglet.graphics.Group):
     def __init__(self, parent_branch):
         self.parent = parent_branch
         pyglet.graphics.Group.__init__(self)

     def set_state(self):
         glPushMatrix()
         glTranslatef(self.parent.length, 0, 0)
         glRotatef(self.parent.relative_angle, 0, 0, 1)

     def unset_state(self):
         glPopMatrix()
```

Recalling my college lessons on linear algebra, matrix multiplication should be a lot more expensive than what I was doing. 2D rotation matrices are 2 sines and 2 cosines. Multiplying a 2D rotation matrix with a 2D translation matrix implies 4 row-column multiplications, at 2 multiplications and 1 addition each, summing to 2 cosines, 2 sines, 4 additions, and 8 multiplications for every branch. Not counting the recursive multiplications. And 3D are even worse. 9 row-column multiplications at 3 multiplications and 2 additions each, involving ideally only 2 cosines and sines, but the non-cardinal rotation matrices would get very expensive indeed.

If someone could point me to a resource on openGL matrices, or a strong example on how to use them efficiently in for instance this binary tree, I would be very interested. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Note: Since you seem to be sending all the vertices every time you render, it's already *maximally inefficient* as far as the graphics card is concerned.

Comment: As far as the CPU is concerned, the graphics card will do the matrix multiplications if you use matrices, and the CPU will do them if you do them in your code.

Comment: The vertices are transformed by the matrices on the GPU. On the GPU vertices are processed parallel. The GPU is designed to do parallel matrix operations on a bunch of vertex coordinates respectively parallel operations on fragments. That is why we have GPUs.

Comment: If you really wanted _efficient_ animated binray tree visualizations, you would do it completely on the GPU. The only animation parameter you have here is the angle, and that would be the only thing the CPU would have to send to the GPU for each frame. Even though you can't directly implement the recursive algorithm that way on the GPU, it  would still be easy to implement. It can be done attrib-less in a vertex shader, all based on `gl_VertexID` alone.